# Is there a popular footprint for right angle SMT LEDs?

Tags: led, surface-mount, footprint

I am designing a PCB with SMT LEDs at the edges. The LEDs have to be right-angle type (ie. shine sideways).

With regular LEDs I can use an 0805 or 0603 footprint and tell the assembly house to place whatever fits (the type/brightness/etc. is non-critical).

I have looked at right-angle LEDs and of course there is an abundance of them, but they seem to have many different footprints.

**Is there a popular footprint for small and cheap right-angle SMT LEDs?**

Answer (score 0):

No.  And I would say 0805 and 0603 are not especially popular either.   On Digikey they have 2,491 right angle indicator LEDs 24 are 0805 and 19 are 0603.  And that include duplicates  of reels, DigiTape, and cut tape.

If you really want to know which is most popular go to digikey and click on each "package / case" and see how many are remaining.

LINK: [Digikey Right Angle Indicator LED](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/optoelectronics/led-indication-discrete/105?k=&pkeyword=&pv69=352&FV=ffe00069&quantity=0&ColumnSort=0&page=1&pageSize=25)